# Disable JS merging in shopware 6

Tags: shopware, shopware6

How we can disable js merging in shopware 6 I am not able to find out the order it's adding the js.

I tried to disable it using command but it's only has option to enable or disable compilation.

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean by merging? Do you refer to the build process of the administration or storefront? What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but in the compiled all.js you can see how all the plugins, etc. are being added in a specific order.

[image]

Comment: I think this is the question, how can this be avoided (having everything minified in the all.js) for debugging?

Answer (score 0):

You can run the storefront in 'hot-proxy'-mode for debugging the non-minified, unmerged JS by
executing `./psh.phar storefront:hot-proxy` in your CLI and then
opening it at the proxy-port being dumped in the CLI after execution.